# Call function to update database values periodically in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, scheduling, razor-pages

I have a razor pages web application wherein users are given tasks to perform based on what day it is relative to another date. In one situation, I need a task to perform once every 7 days, and I let the user know the task needs to be done by flipping a boolean to false. In another situation, I have deadlines where after the deadline passes, I flip another boolean false. The starting point of the scheduled task and the deadlines are all saved and static. Then, the boolean will go back true after the task is accomplished.

My question is what is the best way to implement a call to this checking function such that it runs once every day and checks for bools to flip?

Comment: [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or [Quartz.Net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Comment: Or if it's nothing too complex you can also use an [IHostedService with a timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks).

Comment: @Compufreak Could you define "too complex"? I think I will only need For loops and If statements, so I'm thinking it should be okay, right? I'm trying to make this application with only the base .NET for as much as I can, but I will use third party tools if necessary.

Comment: Yeah this should be fine. I use the same approach - you just need to, make sure to implement a robust error handling so your service does not stop working if any kind of exception occures. IIRC this can otherwise crash your complete application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timed Background Task set to 24 hours

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio